# В angular после события click хочу поменять название кнопки но ничего не меняется?

Tags: angular

В ангулар после нажатия на кнопку хочу поменять название кнопки но после изменения innerHTML  нечего не меняется .

[вот ссылка на код](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dunwwv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: у вас там `innerHtml` а не `innerHTML` :)))

Answer (score -1):

app.component.html

```
<button (click)="showMessage()">{{buttonName}}</button>
```

app.component.ts

```
buttonName = 'click';

showMessage(){
this.buttonName = 'clicked';
}
```